# Parameters passed into a before_filter method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `application_contorller` I have the method:

```
def authorize(message = "Please Login")
    if current_user.nil?    
        redirect_to :root, alert: message 
        return
    end
end
```

And I want to be able to put a custom message in if needed so that I can call this method from many different controllers in a `before_filter`.

For example in another controller I have:

```
before_filter :authorize, except: [:index,:show]
```

How can I pass the `message` param into the `:authorize` method call in the `before_filter` in order to show a different message?

Comment: @JeffLaJoie I looked at that, but that seems to be for calling a method in the same controller - not from the application controller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a way to pass parameters to a request callback when you define it using a symbol. You can instead use a block:

```
before_filter(only: [:index, :show]) { authorize('You forgot to login') }
```